# In war with exercise, any future for me?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

I love theory with theorems, definitions & proofs, but i don't like exercise, I need more context around it. Is there a different way of practicing theory except given exercises, maybe some applied math projects?
For example perfect example is nand2tetris project, is there something like that for math?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: given any mathematical arena one can typically play two games. One, how can I weaken the theory and still retain essential features. Two, how can I specialize the theory and what new features appear. These are interesting exercises.

Comment: Well, I think that (by making a BIG generalization), mathematicians can be divided in two groups (of course, there is a continuum between them, but that is not my point): Theory Builders, and Problem Solvers. But... any one of them you fit yourself in, you need the other. If you are a problem solver, you need theory to solve problems. If you are theory builder, you need exercises to check if you are understanding the theory well enough. I think there is no running from it.
EDIT: And the two things are not really opposed, but rather interconnected.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo thanks on answer! Help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that if the exercises in the book you are working on seem too difficult and lack context, the likely problem is that the book is above your level. The solution to this seems to be to drop down a notch. For example at the moment I need to learn measure theory, so I tried reading "Real and Complex Analysis" by Rudin (I found a basically brand-new copy of it in a second-hand bookshop for a very low price) and found it seems like gibberish. A few days ago I started on a much lower level book, R.G. Bartle "Integration and Lebesgue Measure" and the exercises seem quite pleasant. I'm sure this reflects my level rather than the quality of either book.